# <style> not working as intended for <table> on Outlook 2007

Tags: css, vb.net, email, outlook-2007

## Problematic

< style> tags don't seem to work properly in an Email sent to Outlook 2007.

## Context

I use an asp.net server to send an Email with a table. This table has the inputs that the client entered.

### What it should do

[image: Table (From JSFiddle)]
[PrintScreened from JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tca6/)

### What it does

[image: Table (From Outlook 2007)]
PrintScreened from Outlook 2007 message.

## Stipulations

The VB code doesn't matter (as it sends the Email properly), the problem comes from the `mailMessage.body` text.

Here is the code for it :

```
Dim table As String
Dim mailMessage As New MailMessage()

'There are two multiline textboxes which I want to create a table from
table = "<table><thead><tr><th>Length</th><th>Force</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(length.Text, Environment.NewLine))
    table += "<tr><td>" & Split(length.Text, Environment.NewLine)(i) & "</td>"
    table += "<td>" & Split(force.Text, Environment.NewLine)(i) & "</td></tr>"
Next
table += "</tbody></table>"

mailMessage.Body = table & _
"<style>" & vbCrLf & _
"table {display: inline-table; border:3px solid; border-collapse:collapse;}" & vbCrLf & _
"thead {border:2px solid;}" & vbCrLf & _
"tbody {border:1px solid;}" & vbCrLf & _
"th {border:1px solid; padding:3px;}" & vbCrLf & _
"td {font-size:90%; border:1px solid; padding:3px; text-align:left;}" & vbCrLf & _
"</style>"
```

This *should* translate into [*this*](http://jsfiddle.net/6tca6/), but something goes wrong in the process.

From https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/, all the `style` commands I used should work..

## Question

What have I done wrong?

### Update 1

I tried to put the `<style>` tags in front of the table, it did this :

```asp
<style>[...]</style>
<table>[...]</table>
```

[image: Style in front]

It seems like the last CSS command overwrites all of the previous ones (table 3px border gets overwritten by `td`...)

I tried *JRulle* proposition, it gave this :

[image: JRulle's proposition]

Both of those will work in case no solution is found, but I would really want to have the table borders bigger than the inner borders for ... style. Is that possible?

### Update 2

Following *JRulle's* second proposition :

**Without collapse**

[image: W/o Collapse]

This is an expected result, as my first row are `<th>`, so the style should not draw borders for them.

**With Collapse**

[image]

This is now really weird, it seems the collate function actually put the inner borders OVER the outside borders...

Comment: HTML email is a fickle, tricky beast... test, test again and retest in different clients to ensure the proper display of your content. I find it makes things work much much more consistently to use in-line styles whenever possible and to use HTML attributes in lieu of css styles when available (i.e. width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I could properly draw the border of the table was by hardcoding every border with `border-left` `border-bottom` etc.

The code at the end (using inline style) is this :

```
table = "<table style=""border: 3px solid; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 3px;"">" & _ 
    "<thead><tr><th style=""border-right: 1px solid;"">Length</th><th>Force</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(length.Text, Environment.NewLine))
    If i = 0 Then
        borderTop = "2px"
    Else 'i > 0 then
        borderTop = "1px"
    End If
    table += "<tr><td style=""border-right: 1px solid; border-top: " & borderTop & _ 
        " solid;"">" & Split(length.Text, Environment.NewLine)(i) & "</td>"
    table += "<td style=""border-top: " & borderTop & " solid;"">" & _ 
        Split(force.Text, Environment.NewLine)(i) & "</td></tr>"
Next
table += "</tbody></table>"

mailMessage.Body = table
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors are are showing are with your table borders, so try one of these solutions:

One: Set Border values as inline TD attributes like so:

```
<table border="1">
```

Two: Set border css properties separately:

```
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
```

*I dont have access to Outlook 2007 to test these for you... sorry

**Update 1:**

Adjusted styles based on your feedback:

```
table { 
  border-width: 3px; 
  border-color: black; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
td { 
  border-width: 1px; 
  border-color: black; 
  border-style: solid; 
}
```

*basically, you need to set the borders differently for the different tags then also collapse the borders (use this in tandem with attribute border="1")

Comment: Tried it, see the results in my updated question. I would really prefer to have the outside borders bigger than the inner ones. If it is possible

Comment: take a look at what i added to my answer for update 1

Comment: Have a look at my Update 2 and answer. Thanks for your help, you made me find a way to make it work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it make a difference if you swap the order of the style declarations? td {...} then table {...}

Comment: I also tried that, it didn't change anything, as the style just apply in the order they appear in the html : `<table><tbody><tr><td> [...]` Which I think is the reason the borders called for the TDs overwrite the previously called TABLE borders. Which **doesn't** happen on any web based HTML..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use style tags in emails. You can only use inline styling which means hardcoding the styles directly in to the HTML. Unfortunately, this is still the case these days!

[Read more here.](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/css-in-html-email)

Comment: I already tried that, the problem with it is that the borders of my < td> and < th> overwrite the borders in <table> and <theaders>. Which renders an ugly table. And there is nowhere written that <style> doesn't work in Email, they actually should work. Your source only speaks of not writing CSS in < header>